# calculating percentages in form processing

Tags: php, calculator, percentage

I have a simple calculator form which asks for basic budget information.

User Name, Paycheck 1 amount, Paycheck 2 amount, rent, utilities.....

Somehow I need to calculate all the expense fields individually as a percentage of the total income. I'm just not sure how to do this. I have gone through a ton of tutorials and none of them worked even with the source files.

Here's my processing php. Sure could use a push in the right direction. Thanks!

```
    <?php
    if ($_POST['sum1'] == "yes") 
    { 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $month = $_POST['month']; 
    $year = $_POST['year']; 
    $pay1 = $_POST['pay1']; 
    $pay2 = $_POST['pay2']; 
    $other1 = $_POST['other1']; 
    $other2 = $_POST['other2']; 
    $rent = $_POST['rent']; 
    $repair = $_POST['repair']; 
    $utility = $_POST['utility']; 
    $invest = $_POST['invest']; 
    $insure = $_POST['insure']; 
    $groceries = $_POST['groceries']; 
    $student = $_POST['student']; 
    $travel = $_POST['travel']; 
    $ccard1 = $_POST['ccard1']; 
    $ccard2= $_POST['ccard2']; 
    $cell = $_POST['cell']; 
    $cable = $_POST['cable']; 
    $misc1 = $_POST['misc1']; 
    $misc2 = $_POST['misc2'];
    $ttl_inc = $pay1+$pay2+$other1+$other2; 
    $ttl_exp = $rent+$repair+$utility+$invest+$insure+$travel+$ccard1+$ccard2+$cell+$cable+$misc1+$misc2+$student+$groceries; 
    $total = $pay1+$pay2+$other1+$other2-$rent-$repair-$utility-$invest-$insure-$travel-$ccard1-$ccard2-$cell-$cable-$misc1-$misc2-$student-$groceries;  

    echo "<h2>Budget Recap Prepared For {$name} For Period: {$month} {$year}</h2> <br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<h3>Income</h3> <br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Pay Period 1: $ {$pay1} <br />";
    echo "Pay Period 2: $ {$pay2} <br />";
    echo "Other Income 1: $ {$other1} <br />";
    echo "Other Income 2: $ {$other2} <br />";
    echo "<strong>TOTAL INCOME: $ {$ttl_inc} </strong><br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<h3>Expenses</h3> <br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Rent: $ {$rent} <br />";
    echo "Utilities: $ {$utility} <br />";
    echo "Groceries: $ {$groceries} <br />";
    echo "Insurance: $ {$insure} <br />";
    echo "Credit Card 1: $ {$ccard1} <br />";
    echo "Credit Card 2: $ {$ccard2} <br />";
    echo "Repairs/Maintenance: $ {$repair} <br />";
    echo "Savings/Investments: $ {$invest} <br />";
    echo "Student Loans: $ {$student} <br />";
    echo "Transportation: $ {$travel} <br />";
    echo "Cell/Mobile Phone: $ {$cell} <br />";
    echo "Cable/Internet/Other: $ {$cable} <br />";
    echo "Other Expenses 1: $ {$misc1} <br />";
    echo "Other Expenses 2: $ {$misc2} <br />";
    echo "<strong>TOTAL EXPENSES: $ - {$ttl_exp} </strong><br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<strong>NET INCOME FOR {$month} {$year} :  $ {$total} </strong><br />";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It's simple basic (real life) math. Add them all up then divide by 100. "Percent" is made of 2 words: `per` and `cent`. `Cent` being hundred in latin.

Comment: Could you point to some of those tons of tutorials you gone through in search for finding a solution to calculate percentages ? Just curious !

Answer (score 0):

the percentage is the ratio expressed as a fraction of 100.
the ratio for the rent to total income is rent / total income
for example if the rent is 30 and total income is 100 the ratio = 0.33333
then you have to multiply it by 100 to get 33.333 and using the round() function will get rid of the unneeded decimal places and you will get 33 add the % sign and you will get a well formatted percentage.

For example:

```
$rent_percentage = round(($rent / $ttl_inc) * 100) . '%';
```

Comment: This answer is too short and doesn't meet SO quality standards. 
Please improve it by adding some explanations in order to make
it useful for the community and not only for the OP.